# Error JAVA_HOME set invalid directory

Tags: android-studio

Estoy tratando de compilar mi aplicación híbrida la cual desarrollo con ***ionic framework***, pero me he encontrado con un error acerca de la variable de entorno JAVA_HOME

**Desarrollo usando:**

- Windows 10
- Brackets Editor
- Firfox Developer Edition
- Instalado el **jdk1.8.0_25**
- Android Studio 1.5

**Variables de entorno**

- JAVA_HOME  -- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25

Error completo

[image: set JAVA_HOME]

```
C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v5.3;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin;C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\pedromiguel\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\pedromiguel\AppData\Local\atom\bin;
```

Comment: Añade /bin a la ruta que ya haz especificado, y me comentas.

Comment: Aunque acabo de revisar y mi JAVA_HOME está como el tuyo C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75, ignora lo que escribí arriba ahaha

Comment: Estoy probando @RosendoRopher, ya te comento, en dado algo voy a tener que poner la ruta de _**path**_ cmpleta

Comment: Reiniciaste tu PC despues de los cambios en el path?

Comment: Ya lo voy hacer estaba guardando todo 
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin  , tambien lo agregue al path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Podrías revisar si hiciste esta serie de pasos?

Paso 1:
En variables de sistema, agrega una nueva llamada `JAVA_HOME` y apúntalo a la carpeta del JDK, ejemplo:

(Sin incluir la carpeta bin)

```
C:\Program files\Java\jdk1.8.0
```

Paso 2:

Actualizar variables del sistema,para eso, encontrar `PATH`, click para editar y agregar al final `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`, separado por un `;` ejemplo:

```
C:\otrascosas;mascosas;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

Último paso:

Para verificar que todo se hizo bien, abrir la consola y escribir:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

Esto debe de arrojar el directorio del JDK

Para mas info click [aquí](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/)

Comment: De igual forma voy a actualizar el jdk y ya te comento si utilizando tu metodo sirve

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió esto, de igual forma actualice el jdk, gracias de nuevo

Comment: De nada amigo, para eso estamos, se hace lo que se puede :)

Comment: me apareció esto después que termino

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated api.
Note: Recompile with xlint:deprecation for details.

Answer (score 0):

En tu captura veo que tienes `C:\Program Files\Java\{version}\bin`, omite el `\bin` para que quede así `C:\Program Files\Java\{version}`

Comment: Estoy probando, no se si quieres que te pase mi ruta de path completa?

Comment: Aun persiste el error revisa de nuevo que voy a colocar la ruta d path completa

Comment: Lo correcto es borrar el `\bin` revisa bien si es que se escapa algun otro detallito, un espacio en blanco, si es la ruta correcta, cosas como esas.

Comment: Bueno creo que la ruta si es ya que la saco del disco C y de la carpeta java donde quedo instalado el jdk

Answer (score 0):

Desde la línea de comandos utiliza el comando:

```
SET
```

para ver la ruta correcta de la variable `JAVA_HOME`

regularmente se encuentra definida como:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\[version]
```

**Actualización:**

`JAVA_HOME` debe ser el directorio que contiene java y no el folder `\bin`:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\
```

El valor de tu variable de ambiente `JAVA_HOME` es incorrecto, debe ser:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\[version]\
```

Cambialo y este mismo valor es el que debe usar `Ionic`.

Comment: Me aparece esto @Elenasys

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin

Comment: OK cambia entonces el path en tu configuración a C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin y dime que resultado tienes.

Comment: Bueno, ya lo hice pero voy a compilar haber si me sale el mismo error

Comment: Aun persiste el mismo error, una pregunta, es necesario agregar a la ruta _**path**_ del sistema para que me reconozca o no lo es?

Comment: Una pregunta @Pedro, ¿reiniciaste tu PC despues del cambiar el PATH?

Comment: No lo he hecho, dame un momento, haber que tal me va, estaba guardando y cerrando todo, te respondo cualquier cosa agregue la ruta JAVA_HOME  = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin, tambien al path

Comment: Al final el valor de JAVA_HOME es C:\Program Files\Java\[version]\ , revisando la configuración de Ionic debe ser así.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder hacer esto debemos de dar clic derecho sobre nuestro icono de windows y dar clic en sistema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de eso debemos de ir a "Configuración avanzada del sistema":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego debemos de ir a la opción de Variables de entorno:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de dar clic se nos abrirá una ventana con la variables existentes y a continuación debemos de hacer lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego damos clic en nueva y vamos a hacer lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nombre de la variable: JAVA_HOME y de hay debemos de seleccionar el directorio donde esta guardado nuestro jdk:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya con esto finalizamos la creación de JAVA_HOME ya solo damos clic en Aceptar y cerramos todas las ventanas que hemos abierto lo mas recomendable es reiniciar el equipo para que detecte la variable nueva.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, lo solucione de igual manera ya hace tiempo